# How do I import .py files from a directory that is parallel to current script's parent directory?

Tags: python-2.7, python-import, sys

I have a python script that wants to import another `.py` file in a directory that is on the same level of its parent directory, the file system like the following

```sh
.
├── __init__.py
├── obslib
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── jet
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── fakepdf.py
│       ├── fakepdf.pyc
│       ├── jet_mellin.py
│       ├── reader.py
│       ├── residuals.py
│       ├── theory.py
│       └── theory.pyc
├── readme.md
└── tools
    ├── README.md
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── bar.py
    ├── config.py
    ├── inputmod.py
    ├── multiproc.py
    ├── parallel.py
    ├── randomstr.py
    ├── reader.py
    ├── residuals.py
    ├── storage.py
    └── tools.py
```

File `jet_mellin.py` in directory `jet` wants to import, say, class `BAR` in `bar.py` in directory `tools`, it should be fine to just write

```py
from tools.bar import BAR
```

However, I get error

```sh
ImportError: No module named tools.bar
```

Then I tried

```py
from ..tools import bar
```

and get

```sh
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

The only way I could make it work is following

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../../tools/')
from bar import BAR
```

But this would give rise to ambiguous situation if I want to have another script also called `bar.py` in some other directory. So I would like to be able to specify the path for an import like in `from ..tools import bar`. Could you please help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When reading the dupe, please skip the accepted answer and go to the +300 bountied answer.

Comment: @wim I think his solution can only be used for Python 3 due to `venv`, I am working in Python 2.7...

Comment: You can do the same with `virtualenv`.